# NSRegularExpression regex replace Greek Unicode text

Tags: regex, swift

I have a HTML string I'm displaying in a UIWebView. There's some Greek text, Unicode range U+0370–U+03FF, that I'd like to display in a different font, by enclosing in a span. I can search for \p{script=Greek}:

```
let regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(\\p{script=Greek})", options:nil, error: nil)
let newString = regex!.stringByReplacingMatchesInString(entryText, options: nil, range: NSMakeRange(0, count(entryText)), withTemplate: "<span class=\"gr\">$1</span>")
```

But this replaces each character. I couldn't figure out how to specify a range with \x… or \u.

Comment: The lower range is bigger than the upper. You can try either u or x constructs: `[\u3700-\u3FFF]+ ` or `[\x{3700}-\x{3FFF}]+`

Comment: @sln The lower Unicode code point was wrong in the original unedited question; the range should be U+0370–U+03FF. U+3700 through U+3FFF are in the block CJK Unified Ideographs Extension A.

Comment: @sin I tried both, and this even seemingly goes against convention & the documentation, but ([\u{0370}-\u{03FF}]+) worked.

Comment: Oh, yeah, JS now is on a `\u{}` construct now, good luck! I believe its still UTF-16 though, so be careful should u need > U+FFFF.

Comment: @sin forgot I also needed Greek Extended. Couldn't figure out how to specify multiple scripts using "script=" but specifying the additional range U+1F00–U+1FFF works great.

Comment: @empedocle: `[\\p{script=...}\\p{script=...}]+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression quantifier `+` means "match one or more of the preceding element", and can be used in your case: `(\\p{script=Greek}+)`. It is greedy, which means it will cause a single match to include as many characters as it can, which in your case is all consecutive Greek characters.